# com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata:getHosts() returning incorrect state

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

Any reason why `com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata:getHosts()` would return state `UP` for a host that has shutdown?

However, `nodetool status` returns `DN` for that host.

No matter how many times I check `Host.getState()`, it still says `UP` for that dead host.

This is how I'm querying `Metadata`:

```
cluster = DseCluster.builder()
    .addContactPoints("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3")
    .withPort(9042)
    .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(2000))
    .build();

cluster.getMetadata().getAllHosts();
```

EDIT: Updated code to reflect I'm trying to connect to 3 hosts. I should've stated that the cluster I'm connecting has 3 nodes, 2 in DC1 and another in DC2.

Also, whenever I relaunch my Java process running this code, the behavior changes. Sometimes it gives me the right states, then when I restart it again, it gives me the wrong states, and so on.

Comment: Is this host in another DC?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, in fact, the CONTACT_POINTS provided are 3 host addresses. 2 in DC1 and 1 in DC2.

Comment: @AlexOtt Updated the original question to include these details.

Comment: Driver developer is answered on Slack - it looks for Remote DCs the change events could be lost...

Comment: @AlexOtt Not sure I follow. But is there a way to programmatically get the same state value returned by `nodetool status` via the driver or other SDK?

Comment: you can of course look into system_peers table, but it's version dependent. I would better chase developers to understand why your situation happens...

Answer (score 0):

I will post an answer which I got from the datastaxacademy slack:

> `Host.getState()` is the driver's view of what it thinks the host
>   state is, where `nodetool status` is what that C* node thinks the
>   state of all nodes in the clusters are from its view (propagated via
>   gossip) There is not a way to get that via the driver